# list comprehension with global variable

Tags: python, list

I want to convert the following code to list comprehension:

```
l=''
for i in ["1","2"]:
   l = l+i
print(l)

12
```

How do I do it? The following code doesn't work:

```
l=''
print([l+i for i in ["1","2"]][-1])

2
```

Comment: `l+i` doesn't update `l`

Comment: `"".join(["1", "2"])` would suffice. Actually, you would _need_ `join`. A list comprehension merely makes a list. To make a single string from the list, you need to join the string elements.

Comment: `l = l + i` is a statement, not an expression. You can't put statements in list comprehensions -- only expressions go there. PEP 572 added an assignment expression to Python, but (ab)using it this way would be evil (which is to say, it would be making needlessly hard-to-read code that only runs in very new versions of Python).

Comment: ...to _do_ the evil thing I referred to might look like `l = ''; ([l := l + i for i in ["1","2"]], l)[1]`; note that it only works in Python 3.9 and later.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: So how do I put a statement inside an LC and how do I use a Global variable inside LC, using PEP 572

Comment: @user3141181, I showed you that in the comment above. And, as I said, it's evil; you shouldn't write that and expect any other Python developer to be something other than repulsed by it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the 'evil' solution. Exactly, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension isn't necessary here. You just need to join the strings together:

```py
result = ''.join(["1","2"])
print(result) # Prints 12
```